# Search feature with multiple criteria - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

How can i create a search page with multiple criteria where at least a criteria should be checked.

Table Structure

- ID [pk]
- Name
- Sex
- Location

I want to create a search form where user will be able to search by name or by name,sex or by name,sex,location or any such combination among [name,sex,location]

How to design the query ?

`Edit`
i am not asking for checking atleast a single option has value [js validation], i am asking for the query !
I'll use **mysqli prepared statement** !

Comment: You have two separate questions:  "how to require at least one field on a form before submission" (javascript validation) and "how to write a php script to build an SQL statement using dynamic POST values as search criteria".  Consider posting two separate questions, one for each of these.

Comment: @AJ, nope, i'm looking for only to build an SQL statement using dynamic POST values as search criteria

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and narrowing the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check to see if the post for a particular field is empty, if it's not then append the corresponding WHERE clause to the query.  Something in the form of the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';
$where = array();
$values = array();
$types = '';

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $where[] = 'name = ?';
    $values[] = $_POST['name'];
    $types .= 's';
}

if (!empty($_POST['sex'])) {
    $where[] = 'sex = ?';
    $values[] = $_POST['sex'];
    $types .= 's';
}
...
$sql .= implode(' AND ',$where);
$values = array_unshift($values, $types);

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $values);
...
```

Comment: @Sourav I modified it to use mysqli, it's untested though.  Make sure each conditional adds the proper type (integer, string, etc.) and in theory it should bind everything.