# PHP/MySQLI multiple search

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I've been trying to get a php/mysqli simple search up and running, but i can't seem to get it working. I've been following some directions i found in an earlier question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036084/1503704)) but it still won't work.

```
$sql = 'SELECT product_title FROM product ';
$where = array();
$values = array();
$types = '';

if (isset($_GET['searchText']) and $_GET['searchText'] != '') {
    $where[] = 'WHERE product_title = ?';
    $values['titel'] = $_GET['searchText'];
    $types .= 's';
}

if (isset($_GET['searchCategorySelect']) and $_GET['searchCategorySelect'] != '') {
    $where[] = 'WHERE product_categoryid = ?';
    $values['category'] = $_GET['searchCategorySelect'];
    $types .= 's';
}

$sql .= implode(' AND ',$where);
$values = array_unshift($values, $types);

$search_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$search_stmt->bind_param($values);
$search_stmt->execute();
```

That results in this error message: 
"Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in..."

Some advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should also check where you're setting your `$where` variable - you're including a `WHERE` with each of them; so if both are set, your SQL statement will end up with two `WHERE`s in it.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, it's changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param expects minimum of 2 parameters, but you are passing one

Syntax:

```
bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
```

Where

> **Parameter:** Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named
>   placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.
>
> **Variable:** Name of the PHP variable to bind to the SQL statement
>   parameter.
>
> **data_type:** Explicit data type for the parameter using the PDO::PARAM_*
>   constants. To return an INOUT parameter from a stored procedure, use
>   the bitwise OR operator to set the PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT bits for
>   the data_type parameter.
>
> **length:** Length of the data type. To indicate that a parameter is an
>   OUT parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the
>   length.

You could also do it like this:

```
$values = array_unshift($values, $types);
call_user_func_array (array ($search_stmt, 'bind_param'), $values);         
$search_stmte->execute();
```